# using Jquery and Ajax to populate dropdown

Tags: jquery, ajax, cascadingdropdown

I am trying to dynamically populate a drop down based on a selection of another drop down. I have this working in my development environment however it does not work when I promote it to the IIS server in one instance. I use the same code in two places Create and Edit. When you first come into the screens it loads a Manufacturer drop down and then depending on what you select it will load the Model drop down. This works for Create however not for Edit. With the Edit I have an additional functionality where I pass an initial value to the drop down. This works however when I then select a new Manufacturer I get an error when it tries to load the Model drop down. In the Response Header when I debug, I get a `Content-Type: text/html` instead of `:json` as expected. I feel it has something to do with how I am passing this initial value as I don't know what it could be on the IIS server as it works in one area and not the other.

My Controller's GET Edit

```
PopulateModel(manufacturer.ManufacturerID, manModel.Model);

private void PopulateModel(int? manufacturerID, object selectModel = null)
    {
        var model = db.ManufacturerModels
            .Where(x => x.ManufacturerID == manufacturerID)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Model);

        ViewBag.dropdownModel = new SelectList(model, "Model", "Model", selectModel);
    }
```

View Edit -

```
@Html.DropDownList("dropdownModel", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })

$('#dropdownManufacturer').change(function () {
            $('#dropdownModel').empty();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Device/GetModelsByManufacturerID",
                datatype: "Json",
                data: { manufacturerID: $('#dropdownManufacturer').val() },
                success: function (data) {

                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        $('#dropdownModel').append('<option value="' + value + '">' +
                            value + '</option>');
                    });
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert("Error Ajax not working: " + error);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: `datatype: "Json",` should be `dataType: "json",`

Comment: I bet you will see some console messages if you hit F12

Comment: remember the $.each is about 8 times slower than a simple for loop

Comment: I changed it to `"json" and still receive the error. I am debugging using FireFox Firebug. This is where I saw the response header.

Comment: did you change `datatype` to `dataType`

Comment: Please feel free to delete this. It is not useful for others

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue. In the Request URL it was missing a piece of information. For some reason, in the Create view it was going to the correct URL however the Edit view it wasn't. I had to explicitly tell it where to go. Once I added the missing information it worked as intended,-

Previously I had `url: "/Device/GetModelsByManufacturerID",`
I remedied the issue by amending it to `url: "/RMS_SMM/Device/GetModelsByManufacturerID",`.

Thank-you to everyone who provided suggestions.